# .click jQuery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So I'm running a .click jQuery event. For some reason, it gets called at the start of when the website loads and then does not "activate" or respond after that. I tried changing it to .hover, not sure why exactly, but nothing worked. I'm not sure where to go. Does it have something to do with the positioning in css? I think it might but not sure how to figure out. I'll just show my html, javascript, and css that relates to this problem, let me know if you'd like to see something else.

html:

```
<img id = "logo" style="float: left;" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="72.5" height="100">
```

css:

```
#logo{
    position: fixed;
    right: 90%;
    top: 5%;

}
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").click(function(){console.log("logo was clicked");});
});
```

Again, I think that it may have something to do with the positioning in css... please let me know what you think. I may be doing something stupid that I'm just not noticing.

Comment: *"For some reason, it gets called at the start of when the website loads"*. Well, you are doing `foo(bar())`, which will execute `bar` and pass the return value to `foo`. That's how functions work in JavaScript, the arguments are evaluated first.

Comment: Can you reproduce the result in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @BillyMathews Surprisingly enough, yes.  jsfiddle.net/c5Nq3/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass function in click event handler.

```
 $("#logo").click(function () {
    console.log("logo was clicked");
 });
```

### EDIT

There's another element overlaying the image. Change z-index

Comment: Now it just doesn't do it on startup, and doesn't do it ever. What do you suggest?

Comment: @LiamShalon, Have you wrapped your code in document-ready handler

Comment: yes, let me update the question with more of my code.

Comment: @LiamShalon, See http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/c5Nq3/ it works

Comment: @LiamShalon: Also works fine with the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/c5Nq3/1/.

Comment: So the image that I'm using is a png with only a small part that is clickable... could that be a problem?

Comment: *"So the image that I'm using is a png with only a small part that is clickable"* What do you mean with that there is only a small part clickable? Is the image very small or what? You can adjust the image URL in my fiddle (change the size) and find out.

Comment: @FelixKling I edited the JSFiddle to use my images and it's working perfectly! This is so bazar. Why isn't this working on my website? Let me look into it a bit more now that I know that my code for that specific thing works...

Comment: What's the problem here with my code? I'm completely mind boggled. Not sure what to do now...

Comment: @LiamShalon, Are you dynamically loading HTML? Is img is dynamically created?

Comment: @LiamShalon: Maybe there is another element overlaying the somehow image? It that case the click won't get through.

Comment: the image is local, the reason why it's linked to a url is because jsfiddle doesn't import pictures. linking to the local images isn't the problem...

Comment: @FelixKling That MUST be it... should I just change the z-index?

Comment: @LiamShalon, Yes, change z-index, see what you get

Comment: WOAH... It worked perfectly. I can't believe I didn't think about that. Feel free to add that as a answer to this question and I'll aprove it.

Comment: @LiamShalon: Glad we were able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

put it inside .ready() function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I had this code before higher in my project, you just don't see it. Still getting same result though...